# How to make a list of the list elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have this list1=[['A','B','C'], ['D','E'], ['F','G','H']]

Is there an easy way to have this output:

*output:*

list2=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

Answer (score -1):

You can find several approaches for that here:
[How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

"Flatten a list" is the keyword for it ;-) Unfortunately it can be a bit tricky, but not too difficult!